# 7-Zip script no longer working: 7-Zip cannot find the code that works with archives

Tags: batch-processing, 7zip

I have a script that takes the setup.exe and msi, combines them into a single file, and distributes the file to the required directories. A couple of months ago, this script stopped working for all of my projects. Now, when I run it, I get the error `7-Zip cannot find the code that works with archives`.

The part of the script in question is below:

```
7zG.exe a -t7z "setup.7z" "C:\Code\setup.exe" "C:\Code\Setup.msi"
```

I have 7-Zip command line installed, and the install directory is in my path. I have also tried with 7zG.exe in the directory the script is running from.

This worked in the past, and I can think of nothing that would have changed. I've found several "solutions" to this problem, but they all seem to revolve around making sure 7-zip Command Line is installed and added to the path.

**Addendum**

The script is running from the same directory that the 7zG.exe file resides.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `7za.exe` instead of `7zG.exe` and type this command:

```
7za.exe -y x \...\file.ZIP -ofolderdes\file
```

If you don't want, you can see [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/581377/7zip-command-line-cannot-find-code-that-works-with-archives)

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have 7za installed. When looking for the command line code, I was only able to find something with 7zG.